# Is it possible to manually include a CPAN library in a Perl script?

Tags: xml, perl, scripting, cpan

The situation I am in is that I have written a perl script which uses the CPAN library XML::Simple and tested in an environment which has the ability to install the necessary CPAN library.

However the environment which the script must be run in does not have the permissions to install CPAN libraries. I was wondering if there is some manual way to include the Simple.pm file with my script and include it in the directory with the script? I have tried using 'use' and 'require' to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*edit: I was able to solve the problem by manually downloading the Simple.pm file and using the line require "Simple.pm"; in my code. I think I must have downloaded the incorrect file somehow when I tried this orginally. Thanks.*

Comment: All environments have "the permissions to install CPAN libraries": see App::cpanminus, local::lib et al. It's really only a matter of setting PERL5_LIB to the right location.

Comment: It's a very restrictive University network/server. I do not have permissions to install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by manually downloading the Simple.pm file and using the line require "Simple.pm"; in my code. I think I must have downloaded the incorrect file somehow when I tried this orginally.

Answer (score 5):

Since [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) is a pure Perl module, you could download the package, extract and use it. You will have to use the [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma to specify the directory containing the module.

Suppose your directory structure is (only relevant files have been included):

```
my_app.pl
XML-Simple
XML-Simple/lib
XML-Simple/lib/XML
XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm
```

Your `my_app.pl` will have access to [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) by including the following code:

```
use lib 'XML-Simple/lib';
use XML::Simple;
```

Comment: Also, rlib might be useful here:

`use rlib '../XML-Simple/lib';`.

See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rlib

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly include XML::Simple itself with you module, but then XML::Simple itself depends on other modules. It needs either XML::Parser (which depends on libexpat being around) or XML::SAX. XML::SAX includes XML::SAX::PurePerl, a slow (and incomplete the last time I checked a long time ago) pure-perl parser. Alternatively XML::SAX can use XML::LibXML (depends on libxml2) or XML::SAX::Expat

Bottom line: if you want your application to be self-contained, you need to include at least XML::Simple and XML::SAX, and past a certain volume of data to process, you probably need also a C parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually download the CPAN module on another machine and install it on the target environment? http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/

Comment: No the machine doesn't have the permissions to do that unfortunately.

Comment: If it has the permissions to run your program, it has the permissions to install a module.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
use FindBin;

BEGIN {
  unshift @INC $FindBin::Bin
}
```

Then

```
use XML::Simple;
```

should just work and it enables you to release the package with your script.