# Using CPAN in perl scripts

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm writing a script that uses some CPAN modules. What can I do so that co-workers can use my script without manually installing these CPAN modules?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Perl script install its own CPAN dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664829/can-a-perl-script-install-its-own-cpan-dependencies) Or [Is it possible to manually include a CPAN library in a Perl script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214047/is-it-possible-to-manually-include-a-cpan-library-in-a-perl-script?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply mark them as dependencies for your script. When he installs your script, `cpan`/`cpanm` will automatically install them too if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be shipped and installed, I definitely recommend packaging as a CPAN-style distribution with dependencies declared in the normal way (modules of note: [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla), [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild), [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker).

*However*, there may be the odd occasion when shipping the dependencies with the script itself is desirable. For pure-perl dependencies and having played around a little bit, [App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/module/fatpack) seems to work OK ([cpanm](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3acpanminus) uses it [itself](https://raw.github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm)).